# Встроеные отступы между блоками на основе Bootstrap

Tags: отступы, bootstrap

Между родительским и вложенным блоком на основе Bootstrap есть встроенный отступ. Хотя ширина блоков задана на 100%. Мне нужно их изменить. Как это сделать?

Comment: Изменил частично. Но для row не могу найти настройки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какой блок, такой и правь в bootstrap.css. Например, panel-body ищи и правь padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;

Comment: Выйдет новая версия фреймворка и опять править?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk конечно же я имел ввиду переопределние, что собственно и рекомендуется на сайте самого бутстрепа.

Answer (score 3):

А зачем править. Создать свой CSS и переопредели там свойства. Подключи свой CSS после CSS Bootstrap.